# Design confusion with ViewModel, Model and CollectionView

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, collectionviewsource, icollectionview

This question relates to design help. In it I present a problem, and some solutions I thought of, together with my opinions of the solutions; and finally a solution I think is the correct one. I am seeking validation or challenges to my solutions. Sorry for the long post.

I have a `ConfigActivityGroup` class (model). It represents a group of activities. A user can have many `ActivityGroups`, each containing a name for the group and multiple activities which are strings.

I have a `ConfigActivityGroupVM` which provides Commands for CRUD on `ConfigActivityGroups`

The `ConfigActivityGroupVM` keeps an ObservableList<ConfigActivityGroup> for the `ConfigActivityGroups`. The `ConfigActivityGroupVM` also keeps a `CollectionViewSource` for the ObservableList<ConfigActivityGroup> and presents an `ICollectionView` for the UI to access.

I haven't done the UI yet, but I planned on having the `ICollectionViewSource` bound to a list, from which the user can click an item; and see a text box with the GroupName, and another list with the `Activities` for the `ActivityGroup` adjacent to the first list.

This is all good, as I have a concept of a current `ConfigActivityGroup` provided by the `ICollectionView`. I can use the current `ConfigActivityGroup` to bind to the second UI list to show the `Activities` in the current `ConfigActivityGroup`.

**Problem:**  When I want to build Commands for `CRUD` on the activities of the current `ConfigActivityGroup`.

If the `Activities` in the `ConfigActivityGroup` are in a `List<string>` and I bind them directly to the UI then I have no concept of a "current" activity to which I can bind-to in the UI so that I could have a `DeleteCurrentActivityCommand` command in the VM delete the current activity for the current command.

**First Solution** I had was to, upon selection of a `ConfigActivityGroup` in the VM (through the ICollectionView), to copy the activities from the selected `ConfigActivityGroup` into a new `ObservableCollection<string>` in the VM (which in turn has it's own `ViewSource` and `ICollectionView`). Then, I could have the UI second list to bind to ICollectionView of the activities of the current `ConfigActivityGroup`. As such, my commands would modify the activities' ICollectionView. However, I ran into a roadblock when I tried to make a new activity for the current `ConfigActivityGroup` in which I couldn't set the activities' `ICollectionView.CurrentItem` to be a different activity string (since it's read only).

I thought one solution to that was to box up the activity string in an `ActivityString` class has a single string. Overall, I wasn't too happy with this method.

**Second Solution** I thought, was to make the `List<string>` in the `ConfigActivityGroup` to be an `ObservableCollection<string>`. That would simplify the VM. I hesitate to use this approach since the model is loaded from the database from a non-UI thread through magic `json-deserialisation` (MyCouch + CouchDB) and then problems arise (I think, from memory) when the `ObservableCollection` is accessed from a thread different from its creation thread. I thought that using one of the many thread-safe ObservableCollections was overkill.

**Third Solution** I thought while writing this question was to keep the model `List<string>` for the activities in the `ConfigActivityGroup`. Then, upon a `ConfigActivityGroup` being selected in its `ICollectionView`, initialising a `CollectionViewSource/ICollection` with the `List<string>` of activities directly as the source. That way the UI can bind to the activities directly and the UI can take care of editing the actual activity string; and the concept of a currently selected activity remains, which I can then delete using a command.

I *think* the third approach is the correct approach, but I am open to hearing what the community thinks. This is my first use of MVVM, and i'm trying to keep responsibilities separated and trying to use Commands as much as possible.

**Extra data:**

- Once the ConfigActivityGroup is loaded from the database and put into the VM, it will not be changed by anyone else than the VM itself through the UI.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx bound to CurrentItem.  Or, CommandParameter="{Binding}" to pass the model you wish to CRUD into your command's Execute method. Why not create a very simple prototype to try these out?